# open_id_authentication issue in redmine 2.3 with profile data

Tags: ruby, redmine

I have redmine 2.3 with open id authentication plugin. The code looks like

```
def login
    domain = GoogleAppsAuthSource.find params[:id]
    oid = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=#{domain.name}"
     attributes = [AX_EMAIL, AX_FIRST, AX_LAST]
    authenticate_with_open_id(oid, :return_to => request.url, :required => attributes) do |result, identity_url, profile_data|
      if result.successful?

        email = profile_data[AX_EMAIL].first
        first = profile_data[AX_FIRST].first
 end
end
```

Here the profile data returned from the server is always blank, which is working older version of redemine like 1.3. The exact error getting in console is ,

```
ArgumentError (http://axschema.org/contact/email/ is not a defined simple registration field):
  lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:145:in `complete_open_id_authentication'
  lib/plugins/open_id_authentication/lib/open_id_authentication.rb:121:in `authenticate_with_open_id'
```

when I try to print the profile data object it is

```
############### PROFILE DATA ###############
--- !ruby/object:OpenID::SReg::Response
ns_alias: sreg
data: {}
```

This is my Redmine environment

Environment:
  Redmine version                          2.3.1.stable
  Ruby version                             1.9.3 (i686-linux)
  Rails version                            3.2.13
  Environment                              development
  Database adapter                         Mysql2
Redmine plugins:
  google_apps                              0.1
  redmine_meeting_room_calendar            0.0.1

Following is my System Rails Environment
user@user-desktop:~/PROJECTS/redmine-2.3.1$ rake about
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/user in PATH, mode 040777
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.3 (i686-linux)
RubyGems version          1.8.24
Rack version              1.4
Rails version             3.2.13
Active Record version     3.2.13
Action Pack version       3.2.13
Active Resource version   3.2.13
Action Mailer version     3.2.13
Active Support version    3.2.13
Middleware                ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::Lock, #, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionManagement, ActiveRecord::QueryCache, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ParamsParser, ActionDispatch::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, ActionDispatch::BestStandardsSupport, OpenIdAuthentication
Application root          /home/user/PROJECTS/redmine-2.3.1
Environment               development
Database adapter          mysql2
Database schema version   20130217094251

Please help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the google_apps controller  AX_* code like this

```
 AX_EMAIL = 'http://schema.openid.net/contact/email'
  AX_FIRST = 'http://schema.openid.net/contact/fullname/'
  AX_LAST = 'http://schema.openid.net/contact/last/'
```

And re-initialize profile_data like this:

```
 authenticate_with_open_id(oid, :return_to => request.url,:required => attributes ) do |result, identity_url, profile_data|
      if result.successful?
        profile_data = OpenID::AX::FetchResponse.from_success_response(request.env[Rack::OpenID::RESPONSE])
```

It will work.